# Is the expression $\frac{\alpha^k}{k!}\left|\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{(n-\alpha)^k}-1\right|$ small or even decreasing for large $k$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

Let $\alpha>0$, and let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n>>\alpha$. For every $1\leq k\leq n$, let $E_{n,k}$ denotes the expression
\begin{align}
E_{n,k}:=\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{(n-\alpha)^k}
\end{align}
My **question**: Is the following true?

> There exists a $k_0$ that depends only on $\alpha$
> but not on $n$ and $k$, such that for every $k_0\leq k\leq n$,
> \begin{align}
>  \frac{\alpha^k}{k!}|E_{n,k}-1|\leq\frac{\alpha^{k_0}}{k_0!}|E_{n,k_0}-1| & & (1)
>  \end{align} or even better,  \begin{align}
>  \frac{\alpha^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}|E_{n,k+1}-1|\leq\frac{\alpha^k}{k!}|E_{n,k}-1| & & (2)
>  \end{align}

Plotting out the graph of the function $k\mapsto E_{n,k}$, this seems to be true, but it turns out to be difficult for me to prove (or disprove) it.

---

Here are some of my observations. Firstly the pattern of $E_{n,k}$ as a function of $k$ is well-understood: There does exist a $k_0'$ that depends only on $\alpha$ such that for every $k\geq k_0'$, we have $E_{n,k}<1$, and $E_{n,k+1}<E_{n,k}$ (i.e. $E_{n,k}$ as a function of $k$ is strictly decreasing). An explicit choice of $k_0'$ can be given e.g. by $k_0'=2\lfloor\alpha\rfloor+3$. For these $k$'s, we can then remove the absolute value sign by replacing $|E_{n,k}-1|$ by $1-E_{n,k}$.

However, since $E_{n,k+1}<E_{n,k}$, one must have $1-E_{n,k+1}>1-E_{n,k}$, and in particular, if $k_0\geq k_0'$, then one must have $1-E_{n,k}>1-E_{n,k_0}$. Namely, the inequality sign is *opposite* to that appears in the conjecture above.

Thus if the conjecture above is true, it must be the case that the factor $1/k!$ is playing an important role to "pull down" the value of $1-E_{n,k}$, so that after multiplying $1-E_{n,k}$ by $\alpha^k/k!$ in front, the inequality sign is flipped from $>$ to $<$. (The description above is a bit informal, but I hope it does convey what I'm trying to mean. Please welcome to ask for clarification if it's not clear.) Any proof of the conjecture should then be exploiting this idea, but so far I'm unable to achieve anything.

Anything comment or answer is welcome and appreciated.

---

P.S. I'm not sure what should I tag for this question though. Please feel free to suggest.